# How i can display only three Tab Item at starting in android

Tags: android

i want to display only three tab item, when user visit third tab item only then he will able to see next and same for every other tab item, but at starting i want to display only three.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XI8G7.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a OnTabSelectedListener to the tabLayout and a boolean variable(initialized as true) to check if it is the first time the user clicks on the tab. If it is true, then create more tabs. Else don't.

```
TabLayout guiTabs;
boolean isFirstTime = true;
guiTabs = findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
guiTabs.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            switch(tab.getPosition()) {
                case 0: Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Tab 1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
                case 1: Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Tab 2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
                case 2: Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Tab 3", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                if(isFirstTime)
                {
                    isFirstTime = false;
                    //add new tabs here
                }
                break;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
```